# Gigabyte GA-X58A-UD3R Does Not Boot Into Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bios

I have a Gigabyte GA-X58A-UD3R (Rev 2) with BIOS FA that I want to install Ubuntu on. I have a 3.5" SATA drive from another machine with that version of Ubuntu on it, but instead of booting after I select Ubuntu from grub, it briefly display the Ubuntu logo, then turns off. The same thing happens when I try to install from an 8 GB USB pen drive.

It can boot from FreeDOS on a USB-HDD no problem.

### BIOS Screen Shots

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's an old BIOS based motherboard (as opposed to anything post-2012 which has UEFI instead of BIOS). Yes, you can still install any modern Linux distro in that machine or Windows 10 (Win11 is incompatible). Settings must be adjusted accordingly and there are some incorrect in your case. Namely SATA mode should be preferably set to AHCI, not IDE.

Comment: I did try AHCI, but it does not boot

Comment: If the HDD you transpalanted from the other machine has Ubuntu installed in UEFI mode then it won't boot obviously. Reinstalling is ALWAYS preferable. That said, Ubuntu makes it very easy to "convert" but in this case not really recommended because if the drive has GPT partitioning you'd then need to move partitions around (with a huge risk of data loss) and create a small (1-2MB) unformatted "bios_grub" partition at the beginning of the disk in order to install Grub for BIOS/Legacy.

Comment: The same thing happens when I try to install Ubuntu from an 8 GB USB pen drive. Are there grub flags to help with this, or is some other way to install Ubuntu?

Comment: The way to install is with a properly made USB flash drive. If it doesn't boot then it wasn't correctly "burned" and/or you're using incorrect BIOS settings.

Comment: What is a "properly made USB flash drive"? Is FAT32 important? What else?

Comment: A properly made live/installation media starts with a good ISO. Some downloads may be corrupt, reason why there's a procedure to verify it before burning. Then it must be a known good USB flash drive. The tool used to "burn" the ISO also matters. Depending on which OS you'll be doing it there are good and not-so-good options. Tutorials for all this are available in the same place where you download the ISO from.

Comment: I know the USB flash drive works on other, newer, machines. I also know a similar flash drive runs FreeDOS on this machine. However, the flash drive with the Ubuntu installer fails on this machine only. There must be another parameter to consider.

Comment: There are the parameters already commented: 1. Verify ISO 2. Use a proper tool (if doing it form Windows prefer Balena Etcher and avoid Rufus as it changes a few things users must know the correct options to select before burning. Etcher does a 1:1 copy and the resulting media boots in BIOS or UEFI modes.

Comment: I used Rufus. I will try Etcher. :)

Comment: But first verify the ISO: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: Will do, many thanks!